# How Could I Increase the Accuracy on Contour Detection

Tags: python-3.x, image

I have a study which provides the length and width values of the objects in an image. What I need is to have exact measurements as length and width but my results deviate too little and I need to reach at the exact values.

I have a ready program but it needs to be developed to reach best result.

```
(contours, _) = contours.sort_contours(contours)
for cnt in contours:
box = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
       box = cv2.boxPoints(box) if imutils.is_cv2() else cv2.boxPoints(box)
       box = np.array(box, dtype="float")
box = perspective.order_points(box)
       cv2.drawContours(orig, [box.astype("int")], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
```

To see the dataset I have I am sharing my test image:

> It detects te contours inside of the purple lines but I would like to have it as the yellow lines.

Wht should I update obn my code to reach the aim?

Comment: https://i.imgyukle.com/2019/09/09/ogFNyR.png

Comment: Removed the tag <[processing](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/processing/info)>. [Processing](https://processing.org/) is a flexible software sketchbook and a language for learning how to code within the context of the visual arts.